# Выполнение запроса PHP на AJAX

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Сделал выполнение запроса без перезагрузки страницы на AJAX, но есть одна проблема. Я сделал вывод из mysql и там отображаются все записи из бд, вот скрипт:

```
 $testsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE test='test'");
    while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($testsql)) {
        echo "<a onClick='testa();' id='alink'>".$test[id]."</a><br />"; //10 записей
    }
```

Выводит вот так:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

и при нажатии на неё он выполняет не тот id который я выбрал, а тот который на первом месте, то есть "1". Как сделать что бы при нажатии на 8 выполнял id 8 или нажал на 5 и выполнил id 5 и т.д. а не тот который на первом месте.

```
<script>
    function testa() {
      var alink = $('#alink').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'test.php',
          data: alink,
          success: function(data) {
            $("#alink").text(data);
          },
          error: function(xhr, str){
                alert(data);
            }
        })

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<a onClick='testa(this);'>".$test[id]."</a><br />"; //10 записей
```

Далее JS:

```
<script>
function testa(el) {
    var alink = $(el).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'test.php',
      data: alink,
      success: function(data) {
         $("#alink").text(data);
      },
    })

}
</script>
```

Попробуйте так.

P.S. Вы генерируете множество элементов с одинаковым id. Не надо так. Это первое. Второе: по теме, Вам нужно в функцию передавать именно тот элемент, который хотите обработать. В Вашем варианте - Вы передаете на обработку элемент с id='alink', таких 10, `var alink = $("#alink").serialize();` - обработает всегда первый элемент. Передавая this в функцию - Вы передаете именно нужный элемент, и `$(el).serialize();` (где el - это пришедший элемент в функцию) - обрабатывает нужный Вам.

Comment: Скрипт работает. Но мне ещё кое что надо по этой же теме. 

Есть такой скрипт: 

`echo "<a onClick='testa(this);'>".$test[id]."</a><br />"; //10 записей
echo "<div id='idRef'>".$ref[id]."</div>";`

Мне надо из div передать в файл обработчика.

Comment: тогда лучше передавать какой-то идентификатор в функцию, например `onClick="testa(<?php echo $test['id'] ?>)"`, далее диву и а можно присваивать `id="test-div-<?php echo $test['id'] ?>"` и `id="test-a-<?php echo $test['id'] ?>"` соответственно. Функция:

    function testa(id) {
    
    var divData = $("#testa-div-" + id).serialize();
    var divData = $("#testa-a-" + id).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'test.php',
      data: {fromDiv: divData, fromA: aData},
      success: function(data) {
         $("#alink").text(data);
      },
    })
    
    }

Comment: А можно сделать типо: 

`var idReferer = $(el).text('#idRef');`